# In Java, what is the difference between " " and "\\s"?

Tags: java, regex

`String a = "I am a good boy.";` Then, we call methods of `a`.

As for `String.replace()`

If we call `a.replace(" ","*");` then it returns `I*am*a*good*boy.`

If we call `a.replace("\\s", "*")`, then it returns `I am a good boy.`

In this case, it seems that `" "` and `"\\s"` are two different things.

As for `String.split()`

If we call `a.split(" ","*");` then it returns a string list `[I, am, a, good, boy].`

If we call `a.split("\\s", "*")`, then it returns the same string list `[I, am, a, good, boy]`

In this case, it seems that `"\\s"` and `" "` are the same thing.

So, what is the difference of `"\\s"` and `" "`? Are they same or different? What leads to the same result in `String.split()` and different results in `String.replace()` ?

Comment: " " can match only " " but `\\s` can match vertical as well as horizontal spaces, ie . \n, \r, tab, spaces

Comment: `\s` (or as string literal `"\\s"`) in regex represents whitespace (space, tabulators, line separators and few more). `replace` method doesn't support regex syntax, `replaceAll`, `replaceFirst`, `split`, `matches` do.